# Short story about a man finding people with rich, vivid memories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

From what I remember, this was in a short story collection, perhaps by Isaac Asimov, or similar authors.

The story starts with a man using a device on young kid, asking him to recall or just think about many scenes, the one I remember is flying near clouds. Then the man uses the device on him to experience those recorded memories.

The point of recording those memories was to sell them as entertainment, and the man is a recruiter for the main company producing those memories or dreams en masse, and the kid is being recruited to work as a creator of those memories for sale.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you read this?

Comment: Sounds like "Dreaming Is a Private Thing" by Isaac Asimov. You can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v009n06_1955-12_cape1736/page/n53/mode/2up?view=theater Is that it?

Comment: Definitely  the Asimov story. @user14111, you should enter that as an answer.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, that's the one! Agreed, you can mark as duplicate and look no it to the old question. Thank you!